# I have a list of values from an experement. I want to calculate the best estimate for the mean, how accurately should I quote these values?

Tags: conventions, measurements, error-analysis

Imagine a set of data such as the following: $16,15,14,14,16,17$. To find the best estimate for the mean it is usual to find the mean and quote an uncertainty given by the sample standard deviation divided by the square root of the number of datapoints. In this case the mean is $15.333$..., and the sample standard deviation is $1.121106$, and the number of datapoints is $6$. The best estimate for the error in mean is $0.4576896$. Should I quote the best estimate as being $15.33333 \pm 0.4576896$ , or $15 \pm 0.46$ (as the data in the example is only $2sf$), or should I do something else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Ewan.

The number of significant figures in your uncertainty determines the precision of the value, not the number of significant figures in your data, so I recommend reporting 15.3±0.5.

In this case it is reasonable to round this to "0.5", but the uncertainty should have two  significant figures when the second figure actually is significant. For example,  reporting "±0.1" is very significantly misleading if the calculated uncertainty is "±0.149".

Comment: I agree that the (unbiased) **sample standard deviation**, which uses $n-1$, is commonly used. However, its fine to use the maximum likelihood standard deviation, which uses $n$, if this is explicitly stated. However, the uncertainty of the average value $\bar x = E[x]$ is given by $Sd[\bar x] = Sd[x]/\sqrt{n}$ and does **not** use $n-1$!

Comment: You make a very good point that it is essential to always state how the uncertainties are evaluated, since there are many methods and conventions for assessing and presenting uncertainty. Because $N$ is on the small side here, I just wanted to point out the $N-1$ corrected estimator that is commonly used.

Comment: The sample standard deviation uses $n-1$, $s=Sd[x]=\sqrt{\sum (x_i-\bar x)^2/(n-1)}$. However, the standard deviation of the average value uses $n$, as I stated in my comment. That's why we use $\bar x \pm 1.96 \, s/\sqrt n$ to calculate the 95% confidence interval even if $n$ is "small".

Comment: @Semoi Thanks, you are correct. I had a mental glitch and will fix the answer.

Comment: @Semoi is right. The standard error of the mean is the standard deviation divided by the square root of n, not n-1. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error